# Trocar cor da tabela no Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Olá. Quero trocar o background de uma tabela de acordo com o tipo no DB. Estou usando Laravel 5.5. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Mesma lógica https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281717/99718 . Caso não consiga, poste seu código pois isso irá auxiliar.

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, o que você deve ter em mente é que não é o Laravel que faz a mudança em específico, mas sim uma possível classe que você define na `tr` da tabela como no exemplo abaixo:

```css
.mytable tr td, .mytable tr, .mytable {
  padding:0; margin:0; border:none;
}
.mytable tr.red td { background: red; }
.mytable tr.blue td { background: blue; }
.mytable tr.green td { background: green; }
.mytable tr.yellow td { background: yellow; }
.mytable tr.pink td { background: pink; }
```

```html
<table class="mytable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr><th>nome</th> <th>tipo</th></tr>
  <tr class="red"><td>nome</td> <td>tipo</td></tr>
  <tr class="blue"><td>nome</td> <td>tipo</td></tr>
  <tr class="green"><td>nome</td> <td>tipo</td></tr>
  <tr class="yellow"><td>nome</td> <td>tipo</td></tr>
  <tr class="pink"><td>nome</td> <td>tipo</td></tr>
</table>
```

Sendo assim, para que seu problema seja resolvido você deve fazer algo assim:

```php
<!-- forçando uma lista manualmente para o exemplo -->
<?php
    $lista = [
        ['nome' => 'Foo', 'tipo' => 'red'],
        ['nome' => 'Bar', 'tipo' => 'blue']
        ['nome' => 'Bin', 'tipo' => 'green']
        ['nome' => 'Ids', 'tipo' => 'yellow']
        ['nome' => 'Asd', 'tipo' => 'pink']
    ];
?>

<table class="mytable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th>nome</th>
        <th>tipo</th>
    </tr>
    @for ($i = 0; $i < count($lista); $i++)
        <tr class="{{ $lista[$i]['tipo'] }}">
            <td>{{ $lista[$i]['nome'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $lista[$i]['tipo'] }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endfor
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver, fiz uma validação.

```
    @if( $financa->banco == 1)
      @php $cor = 'red'  @endphp
    @elseif( $financa->banco == 2)
      @php $cor = 'green'  @endphp
    @else
      @php $cor = 'pink'  @endphp
    @endif
```